# Probability under no uncertainty

Tags: probability

My friends ask me a funny question about probability and we have very different ideas about it.

> Consider a list of more than one vocabs. Two brothers study and have
>   dictation on those vocabs. Given that the elder brother can spell $99\%$
>   of the words correctly while the younger brother can spell only $1\%$
>   correctly, if we pick a vocab from the list randomly, what is the
>   probability that both of them spelt this vocab correctly?

The answer given by the proposer of this question:

> Consider the case in which the elder brother and the younger brother
>   know exactly half of the vocabs. Then, P(both of them spelt a random
>   vocab correctly)$=0.5$. This situation can be generalized to that in
>   the question, so the answer is $0.5$.

Though I am not sure how he generalizes the situation...

I argue simply by:

> There is no uncertainty in the situation. Choose a word, the boys will
>   certainly spell it correctly or incorrectly. No probability can be
>   calculated.

But then some more questions arise, like:

> Is it true that for all events that have happened, we cannot talk
>   about their probabilities?

Any idea to enrich the discussion here is welcome.

Comment: The probability given when each brothers knows exactly half of the words is correct only if both brothers know the exact same set of words. All you really can say is that 0.5 is the maximum _possible_ probability, depending on how much the brothers' knowledge overlaps. In the case where one brother knows just 1% of the words, there is only a 1% chance he spells the word correctly, so the chance that he spells it correctly _and_ his brother also spells it correctly cannot be more than 1%.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, we don't have enough information. However, we can look at what information is missing by noting that, regardless of how the vocabularies are assigned, we can allocate them to a total of four groups:

1. Words known by both the older and younger brother ($V_{11}$)
2. Words known by the older brother, but not the younger ($V_{10}$)
3. Words known by the younger brother, but not the older ($V_{01}$)
4. Words not known by either brother ($V_{00}$)

We can then also state that the vocabulary known by the older brother is $V_{1\bullet}=V_{11} + V_{10}$, similarly the vocabulary known by the younger brother is $V_{\bullet 1}=V_{11} + V_{01}$, and the full vocabulary is $V = V_{11} + V_{10} + V_{01} + V_{00}$.

So we know that $V_{1 \bullet} / V = 0.99$ and $V_{\bullet 1} / V = 0.01$, but what we want to know is $V_{1 1} / V$, the fraction of the total vocabulary that belongs to the shared knowledge.

In one extreme, the two vocabularies are disjoint, i.e. the 1% of words the younger brother knows is exactly the 1% of words the older brother doesn't, in which case $V_{11} / V = 0$. In the other extreme, *all* the words the younger brother knows the older one also knows, i.e. $V_{11} = V_{\bullet 1}$ so $V_{11} / V = 0.01$.

On the other hand, if the assignment of words to the two brother's vocabulary is independent, then we're saying that, for example, the younger brother knows 1% of the words the older brother knows and also 1% of the words he doesn't - $V_{\bullet 1} / V = V_{11} / V_{1 \bullet} = V_{01} / V_{0 \bullet} = 0.01$, and in that case then it's not hard to show that $V_{11} / V = 0.01 \times 0.99 = 0.0099$.

Note that I've been talking about the relative sizes of the vocabulary rather than the probabilities of choosing a word from a particular vocabulary, but as long as you choose the word completely at random then they are the same. So if you put the entire vocabulary list into a hat and draw out one word, the probability that the word belongs to the shared vocabulary is equal to the fraction of the list that is shared.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. So, can you give me some examples that we don't have a probability?

Comment: As long as you're choosing a word randomly, you can talk about the probability that the chosen word is in a given set.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $X$ the r.v. given by $X=0$ if the older doesn't know the word and $1$ in other case. Then $P(X=1)=0.99$. For the other brother, define $Y$ analogously. Then, asumming independence, $P(X=1,Y=1)=0.99\times 0.01=0.0099$.